# integracion con protocolo SOAP con PHP Ayuda!

Tags: php, soap, php5

Quiero integrar un servidor (Cliente) al servidor de mi trabajo. El problema es que el cliente usa el protocolo SOAP para el envío de información de datos, algo que actualmente no se ve mucho y no puedo encontrar la información que necesito.

Muestro el código que se conecta al servidor del cliente.

```
<?php class Client{
private $_soapClient = null;
public function __construct(){
    require_once(getcwd() . '/lib/nusoap.php');
    $this->_soapClient = new nusoap_client("http://serverservice/Service.asmx", true);
    $this->_soapClient->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';
}
public function Magento_GrabarPedido(){
    try
    {
        $result = $this->_soapClient->call('Magento_GrabarPedido', array(
            "idVistaMagento" => "string",
            "idPedidoMagento" => "string",
            "productosCarro" => "string",
            "gastosEnvio" => "0",
            "cifCliente" => "string",
            "shipToName" => "string",
            "shipToAddress" => "string",
            "shipToPostCode" => "string",
            "shipToCity" => "string",
            "shipToCounty" => "string",
            "shipToCountry" => "string",
            "shipToPhone" => "string",
            "shipToMail" => "string",
            "observaciones" => "string",
            "formaPago" => "string",
            "newsletter"=> "string",
            "apellido1" => "string",
            "apellido2" => "string",
            "sexo" => "1",
            "fechaNacimiento" => "string"
        ));
        $this->_soapResponse($result);
    }
    catch (SoapFault $fault)
    {
        trigger_error("SOAP Fault: (faultcode: {$fault->faultcode}, faultstring: {$fault->faultstring})", E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
private function _soapResponse($result)
{
    echo '<h2>Result</h2>';
    echo '<h2>Request</h2>' . print_r($result);
    echo '<h2>XML Response</h2>';
    echo $this->_soapClient->responseData;
    echo '<h2>Request</h2>' . $this->_soapClient->request;
    echo '<h2>Response</h2>' . $this->_soapClient;
    echo '<h2>Debug</h2>' . $this->_soapClient->debug_str;
}}?>
```

Al mismo tiempo, tengo un archivo que muestra el resultado

```
<?php 
     require_once(getcwd() . '/Client.php');
     $client = new Client();
     $client->Magento_GrabarPedido();

 ?>
```

Aparentemente con esto algo funciona porque incluso los estilos de esa url "http://serverservice/Service.asmx" los trae a la mía pero devuelve una serie de matrices ilegibles y códigos que no entiendo mucho. Alfinal de todo lo que pude encontrar un error particular

```
2018-08-17 09:38:58.808243 nusoap_client: checkWSDL 2018-08-17 09:38:58.808243 nusoap_client: got wsdl error: XML error parsing WSDL from http://serverservice/Service.asmx on line 1293: Mismatched tag
```

Supongo que lo que me estoy perdiendo es el WSDL ... así que decidí agregar el wsdl a la url con http://serverservice/Service.asmx?wsdl, pero recibí un error nuevamente.

```
Array ( [Magento_GrabarPedidoResult] => Error;It does not find the message in the queue. Check event viewer )
```

Ah, este punto, no sé qué hacer, ni siquiera puedo entender bien el error.
Esta es mi primera pregunta en el foro de programadores, sé que no muchas personas trabajan con esta tecnología, pero necesito una respuesta, por favor. Estoy desesperado.

Comment: please translate your question, this is the spanish version of S; otherwise it will be closed}

Comment: Te recomiendo usar la clase nativa de [SOAP](http://php.net/manual/es/soapclient.soapclient.php) de PHP